# Yii2 обновление базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, yii2

Обновил базу данных на сервере таким образом, удалил старую и сделал импорт новой из локального сервера.
Теперь при входе в backend, после ввода логин и пароль выходит ошибка:

> yii\db\Exception: amnah\yii2\user\models\User does not have a primary key. You should either define a primary key for the corresponding table or override the primaryKey() method. in /var/www/vhosts/infosec.uz/lab.infosec.uz/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php:1036

А если нажать на любую ссылку, ошибка:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'i' in 'where clause' in /var/www/vhosts/infosec.uz/lab.infosec.uz/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php:837
>
> Next yii\db\Exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'i' in 'where clause'
>   The SQL being executed was: `` SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `i`=1 `` in /var/www/vhosts/infosec.uz/lab.infosec.uz/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:628

А после обновления страницы, или нажатия любой ссылки, стоит и не меняется ошибка:

> yii\base\InvalidConfigException: "amnah\yii2\user\models\User" must have a primary key. in /var/www/vhosts/infosec.uz/lab.infosec.uz/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php:184

Я не пойму почему на локальном открывается, а на глобальном ошибка. Как можно решить проблему?

структура таблицы user:

**id (Первичный)    int(11)

role_id int(11) 
status  smallint(6) 
email   varchar(255)

username    varchar(255)

password    varchar(255)

auth_key    varchar(255)

access_token    varchar(255)

logged_in_ip    varchar(255)

logged_in_at    timestamp

created_ip  varchar(255)

created_at  timestamp

updated_at  timestamp

banned_at   timestamp

banned_reason   varchar(255)**

Класс User.php

```
namespace amnah\yii2\user\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\swiftmailer\Mailer;
use yii\swiftmailer\Message;
use yii\helpers\Inflector;
use ReflectionClass;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tbl_user".
 *
 * @property string $id
 * @property string $role_id
 * @property integer $status
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property string $access_token
 * @property string $logged_in_ip
 * @property string $logged_in_at
 * @property string $created_ip
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 * @property string $banned_at
 * @property string $banned_reason
 *
 * @property Profile $profile
 * @property Role $role
 * @property UserToken[] $userTokens
 * @property UserAuth[] $userAuths
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
/**
 * @var int Inactive status
 */
const STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;

/**
 * @var int Active status
 */
const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;

/**
 * @var int Unconfirmed email status
 */
const STATUS_UNCONFIRMED_EMAIL = 2;

/**
 * @var string Current password - for account page updates
 */
public $currentPassword;

/**
 * @var string New password - for registration and changing password
 */
public $newPassword;

/**
 * @var string New password confirmation - for reset
 */
public $newPasswordConfirm;

/**
 * @var array Permission cache array
 */
protected $permissionCache = [];

/**
 * @var \amnah\yii2\user\Module
 */
public $module;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function init()
{
    if (!$this->module) {
        $this->module = Yii::$app->getModule("user");
    }
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    // set initial rules
    $rules = [
        // general email and username rules
        [['email', 'username'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['email', 'username'], 'unique'],
        [['email', 'username'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        [['email'], 'email'],
        [['username'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/u', 'message' => Yii::t('user', '{attribute} can contain only letters, numbers, and "_"')],

        // password rules
        [['newPassword'], 'string', 'min' => 3],
        [['newPassword'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        [['newPassword'], 'required', 'on' => ['register', 'reset']],
        [['newPasswordConfirm'], 'required', 'on' => ['reset']],
        [['newPasswordConfirm'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'newPassword', 'message' => Yii::t('user', 'Passwords do not match')],

        // account page
        [['currentPassword'], 'validateCurrentPassword', 'on' => ['account']],

        // admin crud rules
        [['role_id', 'status'], 'required', 'on' => ['admin']],
        [['role_id', 'status'], 'integer', 'on' => ['admin']],
        [['banned_at'], 'integer', 'on' => ['admin']],
        [['banned_reason'], 'string', 'max' => 255, 'on' => 'admin'],
    ];

    // add required for currentPassword on account page
    // only if $this->password is set (might be null from a social login)
    if ($this->password) {
        $rules[] = [['currentPassword'], 'required', 'on' => ['account']];
    }

    // add required rules for email/username depending on module properties
    $requireFields = ["requireEmail", "requireUsername"];
    foreach ($requireFields as $requireField) {
        if ($this->module->$requireField) {
            $attribute = strtolower(substr($requireField, 7)); // "email" or "username"
            $rules[] = [$attribute, "required"];
        }
    }

    return $rules;
}

/**
 * Validate current password (account page)
 */
public function validateCurrentPassword()
{
    if (!$this->validatePassword($this->currentPassword)) {
        $this->addError("currentPassword", "Current password incorrect");
    }
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('user', 'ID'),
        'role_id' => Yii::t('user', 'Role ID'),
        'status' => Yii::t('user', 'Status'),
        'email' => Yii::t('user', 'Email'),
        'username' => Yii::t('user', 'Username'),
        'password' => Yii::t('user', 'Password'),
        'auth_key' => Yii::t('user', 'Auth Key'),
        'access_token' => Yii::t('user', 'Access Token'),
        'logged_in_ip' => Yii::t('user', 'Logged In Ip'),
        'logged_in_at' => Yii::t('user', 'Logged In At'),
        'created_ip' => Yii::t('user', 'Created Ip'),
        'created_at' => Yii::t('user', 'Created At'),
        'updated_at' => Yii::t('user', 'Updated At'),
        'banned_at' => Yii::t('user', 'Banned At'),
        'banned_reason' => Yii::t('user', 'Banned Reason'),

        // virtual attributes set above
        'currentPassword' => Yii::t('user', 'Current Password'),
        'newPassword' => $this->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('user', 'Password') : Yii::t('user', 'New Password'),
        'newPasswordConfirm' => Yii::t('user', 'New Password Confirm'),
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'timestamp' => [
            'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',
            'value' => function ($event) {
                return gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            },
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Stick with 1 user:1 profile
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
/*
public function getProfiles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Profile::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
*/

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getProfile()
{
    $profile = $this->module->model("Profile");
    return $this->hasOne($profile::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getRole()
{
    $role = $this->module->model("Role");
    return $this->hasOne($role::className(), ['id' => 'role_id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUserTokens()
{
    $userToken = $this->module->model("UserToken");
    return $this->hasMany($userToken::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUserAuths()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserAuth::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne($id);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    return static::findOne(["access_token" => $token]);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->auth_key;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->auth_key === $authKey;
}

/**
 * Validate password
 * @param string $password
 * @return bool
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    // check if we're setting $this->password directly
    // handle it by setting $this->newPassword instead
    $dirtyAttributes = $this->getDirtyAttributes();
    if (isset($dirtyAttributes["password"])) {
        $this->newPassword = $dirtyAttributes["password"];
    }

    // hash new password if set
    if ($this->newPassword) {
        $this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->newPassword);
    }

    // convert banned_at checkbox to date
    if ($this->banned_at) {
        $this->banned_at = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }

    // ensure fields are null so they won't get set as empty string
    $nullAttributes = ["email", "username", "banned_at", "banned_reason"];
    foreach ($nullAttributes as $nullAttribute) {
        $this->$nullAttribute = $this->$nullAttribute ? $this->$nullAttribute : null;
    }

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}

/**
 * Set attributes for registration
 * @param int $roleId
 * @param string $status
 * @return static
 */
public function setRegisterAttributes($roleId, $status = null)
{
    // set default attributes
    $attributes = [
        "role_id" => $roleId,
        "created_ip" => Yii::$app->request->userIP,
        "auth_key" => Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(),
        "access_token" => Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(),
        "status" => static::STATUS_ACTIVE,
    ];

    // determine if we need to change status based on module properties
    $emailConfirmation = $this->module->emailConfirmation;
    $requireEmail = $this->module->requireEmail;
    $useEmail = $this->module->useEmail;
    if ($status) {
        $attributes["status"] = $status;
    } elseif ($emailConfirmation && $requireEmail) {
        $attributes["status"] = static::STATUS_INACTIVE;
    } elseif ($emailConfirmation && $useEmail && $this->email) {
        $attributes["status"] = static::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED_EMAIL;
    }

    // set attributes and return
    $this->setAttributes($attributes, false);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Check for email change
 * @return string|bool
 */
public function checkEmailChange()
{
    // check if user didn't change email
    if ($this->email == $this->getOldAttribute("email")) {
        return false;
    }

    // check if we need to confirm email change
    if (!$this->module->emailChangeConfirmation) {
        return false;
    }

    // check if user is removing email address (only valid if Module::$requireEmail = false)
    if (!$this->email) {
        return false;
    }

    // update status and email before returning new email
    $newEmail = $this->email;
    $this->status = static::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED_EMAIL;
    $this->email = $this->getOldAttribute("email");
    return $newEmail;
}

/**
 * Update login info (ip and time)
 * @return bool
 */
public function updateLoginMeta()
{
    $this->logged_in_ip = Yii::$app->request->userIP;
    $this->logged_in_at = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    return $this->save(false, ["logged_in_ip", "logged_in_at"]);
}

/**
 * Confirm user email
 * @param string $newEmail
 * @return bool
 */
public function confirm($newEmail)
{
    // update status
    $this->status = static::STATUS_ACTIVE;

    // process $newEmail from a userToken
    //   check if another user already has that email
    $success = true;
    if ($newEmail) {
        $checkUser = static::findOne(["email" => $newEmail]);
        if ($checkUser) {
            $success = false;
        } else {
            $this->email = $newEmail;
        }
    }

    $this->save(false, ["email", "status"]);
    return $success;
}

/**
 * Check if user can do specified $permission
 * @param string $permissionName
 * @param array $params
 * @param bool $allowCaching
 * @return bool
 */
public function can($permissionName, $params = [], $allowCaching = true)
{
    // check for auth manager rbac
    // copied from \yii\web\User
    $auth = Yii::$app->getAuthManager();
    if ($auth) {
        if ($allowCaching && empty($params) && isset($this->permissionCache[$permissionName])) {
            return $this->permissionCache[$permissionName];
        }
        $access = $auth->checkAccess($this->getId(), $permissionName, $params);
        if ($allowCaching && empty($params)) {
            $this->permissionCache[$permissionName] = $access;
        }
        return $access;
    }

    // otherwise use our own custom permission (via the role table)
    return $this->role->checkPermission($permissionName);
}

/**
 * Get display name for the user
 * @var string $default
 * @return string|int
 */
public function getDisplayName($default = "")
{
    // define possible fields
    $possibleNames = [
        "username",
        "email",
        "id",
    ];

    // go through each and return if valid
    foreach ($possibleNames as $possibleName) {
        if (!empty($this->$possibleName)) {
            return $this->$possibleName;
        }
    }

    return $default;
}

/**
 * Send email confirmation to user
 * @param UserToken $userToken
 * @return int
 */
public function sendEmailConfirmation($userToken)
{
    /** @var Mailer $mailer */
    /** @var Message $message */

    // modify view path to module views
    $mailer = Yii::$app->mailer;
    $oldViewPath = $mailer->viewPath;
    $mailer->viewPath = $this->module->emailViewPath;

    // send email
    $user = $this;
    $profile = $user->profile;
    $email = $userToken->data ?: $user->email;
    $subject = Yii::$app->id . " - " . Yii::t("user", "Email Confirmation");
    $result = $mailer->compose('confirmEmail', compact("subject", "user", "profile", "userToken"))
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->send();

    // restore view path and return result
    $mailer->viewPath = $oldViewPath;
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Get list of statuses for creating dropdowns
 * @return array
 */
public static function statusDropdown()
{
    // get data if needed
    static $dropdown;
    $constPrefix = "STATUS_";
    if ($dropdown === null) {

        // create a reflection class to get constants
        $reflClass = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
        $constants = $reflClass->getConstants();

        // check for status constants (e.g., STATUS_ACTIVE)
        foreach ($constants as $constantName => $constantValue) {

            // add prettified name to dropdown
            if (strpos($constantName, $constPrefix) === 0) {
                $prettyName = str_replace($constPrefix, "", $constantName);
                $prettyName = Inflector::humanize(strtolower($prettyName));
                $dropdown[$constantValue] = $prettyName;
            }
        }
    }

    return $dropdown;
}
}
```

---

[image: http://lab.infosec.uz/backend/web/]

[image: http://lab.infosec.uz/backend/web/site/login]

[image: http://lab.infosec.uz/backend/web/test-res3-all-types-tests/index]

Каждая ошибка. Только я вот всё равно не вижу.
Вот логи[image: Logs]

[image: POST http://lab.infosec.uz/backend/web/user/login]

[image: GET http://lab.infosec.uz/backend/web/test-res3-all-types-tests/index]
Продолжение
[image: GET http://lab.infosec.uz/backend/web/test-res3-all-types-tests/index]

---

[image: Скриншот страницы дебаг панели]

@edvardpotter,Собственно вот скрин

Comment: Нужно больше информации, покажите: код модели "amnah\yii2\user\models\User", структуру таблицы user.

Comment: @edvardpotter, я исправил и обновил вопрос.

Comment: @edvardpotter, Класс User.php это фреймворковский. Я его не трогал и не как не изменял. Как с нэта скачал года три назад, так он у меня и стоит

Comment: кэш схемы таблиц включен? `php yii cache/flush-all`

Comment: @Blacknife, Нет проблема не с кэшем. Я попробовал открыть в другом браузере, и после ввода логина и пароля, он выдал другую ошибку: does not have a primary key. You should either define a primary key for the corresponding table or override the primaryKey() method. А если нажать на какую то ссылку такую ошибку `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'i' in 'where clause '`. ``The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `i`=1 in /var/www/vhosts/infosec.uz/lab.infosec.uz/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:628``. И после обновления окна, ошибка как в заданном вопросе

Comment: В дебаг панелей что отображается, какая строка вызывает ошибку (не фреймворкские классы)?

Comment: @edvardpotter, У меня не открыта дебаг панель потому не знаю какие классы. Я не в курсе как  это делать. Но почему он на локалке открывает, а на глобальной версии такая ошибка выходит. Мне кажется, что это какая то проблема со схемой базы данных. Но не могу понять какая.

Comment: @edvardpotter, включил debug. ошибка выход во фрейморкских классах

Comment: В ошибке же видно, что где-то формируется запрос на получение данных юзера и вместо id условие по полю i. Похоже опечатка и символ недопечатался. Надо стэк вызовов посмотреть и узнать, где этот запрос формируется. Или поиском по проекту. А то и обновить файлы на проде.

Comment: @fedornabilkin правильно говорит, либо у вас где то в базе вместо "id" написано "i", или наоборот в локальной базе столбец с опечаткой. Покажите скриншот дебага.

Comment: @edvardpotter, Понимаете штука в том, что таблица user это фрейморковская таблица и потому ошибок в структуре быть не должно. И то же самое с кодом, код фрейморковский. Да и если была бы ошибка в коде, тогда бы локальная версия тоже не запускалась. А по поводу дебага не совсем понял, что вас интересует.

Comment: У вас версия yii2 advanced? Нужен скриншот страницы дебаг панели: что, где и когда вызывается, в какой строке.

Comment: @edvardpotter, скриншот выложил ответом.

Comment: @Игнат проверьте в базе что у поля id стоит именно primary key

Comment: @DaemonHK, Да. У поля id стоит значение первичный ключ

Comment: @fedornabilkin, а где вы это увидели?

Comment: Так в тексте ошибки PDOException: неизвестный столбец i в конструкции where

Comment: @fedornabilkin, Мне удалось получить доступ к БД. Я проверил таблицу, всё в порядке. Столбец имеет название "id". И пользователь вроде задан как в локальной версии. Не пойму в чем проблема...

Comment: Так дело не в базе. Где-то в коде вместо id указано i, как первичный ключ и это генерирует запрос вида WHERE i = 1. Я бы поискал все реляции getUser или на крайний случай что-то типа такого 'i'. Если такой запрос формируется, значит в каком-то файле вместо id указано i.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, Не может быть ошибки. Потому что этот код фрейморковский и точно такой же код на локалке стоит и ВСЁ работает. Но я всё равно поищу. Спасибо

Comment: @fedornabilkin, ничего не нашел. А где примерно может этот "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `i`=1" запрос создаваться?

Comment: Обычно в реляциях других моделей. Если на локалке работает, вполне возможно, что какой-то файл не залит или не обновлен, классическая ситуация. Может быть конфиги разные.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, всё заработало! Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всем кто принимал участие большое спасибо. Всё получилось и всё заработало. Только я не понимаю как=(( "Расскажу кратко что было в предыдущей серии" Я закачал **Adminer** на сайт. Логин-пароль у меня есть, тем самым получил доступ к БД. После я удалил таблицу *"user"* и импортировал с локальной БД копию этой таблицы. Попытался зайти, он мне теперь стал писать что пароль не верный. То есть я вообще потерял доступ к backen-ду. На следующий день зашел на сайт, ввел логин-пароль. Всё заработало. Магия. И как получилось не пойму. Только из за таблицы чтоль была проблема... ??? Всем спасибо!